# What's the most efficient way to check multiple hash references in perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, one-liner

I have a multidimensional data structure for tracking different characteristics of files I am comparing and merging data for. The structure is set up as such:

```
$cumulative{$slice} = {
    DATA    => $data,
    META    => $got_meta,
    RECOVER => $recover,
    DISPO   => $dispo,
    DIR     => $dir,
};
```

All of the keys, save `DIR` (which is just a simple string), are references to hashes, or arrays. I would like to have a simple search for KEYS that match "BASE" for the value `DIR` points to for each of the `$slice` keys. My initial thought was to use grep, but I'm not sure how to do that. I thought something like this would be ok:

`my (@base_slices) = grep { $cumulative{$_}->{DIR} eq "BASE" } @{$cumulative{$_}};`

I was wrong. Is there a way to do this without a loop, or is that pretty much the only way to check those values? Thanks!

Edit: Thanks to Ikegami for answering succinctly, even without my fully representing the outcome of the search. I have changed the question a little bit to more clearly explain the issue I was having.

Comment: @zdim They are all hash, or array references of various lengths and values. Yes, I would like to know if there is a more efficient way than looping through all of the values of `$slice` in the hash to determine which `{$slice}->{DIR}` values match what I'm looking for. Thanks again

Comment: (It's awkward and ineffective talking through elaborate comments so I removed them and posted an answer instead. Please see and comment...)

Answer (score 3):

*This was posted for the initial form of the question, before the edit,  and reflects what I did and/or did not understand in that formulation.*

---

The use of `@{$cummulative{$_}}`, with `$_` presumably standing for `$slice`, indicates that the value for key `$slice` is expected to be an arrayref. However, the question shows there to be a hashref.  This is either an error or the question mis-represents the problem.

If the expression in `grep` accurately represents the problem, for values of `$slice` that are given or can be built at will, then just feed that list of `$slice` values to the shown `grep`

```
my @base_slices = grep { $cumululative{$_}{DIR} eq 'BASE' } @slice_vals;
```

or

```
my @base_slices = 
    grep { $cumululative{$_}{DIR} eq 'BASE' } 
    map { generate_list_of_slice_values($_) } 
    LIST-OF-INPUTS;
```

That `generate_list_of_slice_values()` stands for whatever way the values for `$slice` get acquired dynamically from some input.<sup>†</sup>

There is no need for a dereferencing arrow for the key `DIR` (a syntax convenience), and no need for parenthesis around `@base_slices` since having an array already provides the needed list context.

Please clarify what `$slice` is meant to be and I'll update.

---

<sup>†</sup> The code in [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map)'s block gets elements of `LIST-OF-INPUTS` one at a time (as `$_`) and whatever it evaluates with each is joined into its return list. That is passed to [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep) for filtering: elements of its input list are provided to the code in the block one at a time as `$_` and those for which the code evaluates to "true" (in Perl's sense) pass, forming the `grep`'s return list.

Comment: $slice is literally the filename I am parsing for the data structure. I have a list of them in an array, which I have subsequently remembered, and now this question is just, hopefully, an exercise in education.

Comment: @WetCheerios Ah, there -- so you feed `@base_wafs` to your `grep`, like in the first example above.  But then I'm not sure what that string `'BASE'` stands for ... is that a possible filename? Or do youo need to parse that file to extract a string which is tested against `BASE`? (Then that would be done in the `map` in the second example.)

Comment: Can you please update the `map` example to include `BASE` as the search criteria? I apologize, but I do not use `map` often, and need to start, rather than relying so heavily on `grep`

Comment: OK, can you then explain how that `BASE` need be used?  (1) `grep` is a filter -- feed it a list, the code in the `{}` gets an item at a time (in `$_`) and if that code evaluates to true that item passes; the filtered list is returned (2) `map` on the other hand merely transforms an input list -- feed it a list and it computes with each element at a time (again available in `$_`) and returns the new list. ///  So an often used way is to feed input to a `map`, which transforms it into another list, which is fed into `grep` to filter what's needed.  This is my second example.

Comment: [cont'd] Now, what of that do you need? How does `BASE` string figure into all that?

Comment: @ikegami explained it in a way that even I could understand it. When you said when I had put in an array reference to search, rather than the keys for `%cummulative`, it did not click with me. Thanks for answering so promptly, and accurately. The issue with my understanding is not your fault at all. Sometimes, I just need more words to get the point.

Comment: @WetCheerios Thank you for going to trouble to explain that -- and great that you now figured out your problem!  My initial "explanation" just wasn't clear, because I didn't exactly get what was going on in the question (I still don't quite :).  I cleaned up that initial statement.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```perl
@{$cumulative{$slice}}
```

It gets the value of the array referenced by `$cumulative{$slice}`. But `$cumulative{$slice}` is not a reference to an array; it's a reference to a hash. This expression makes no sense, as results in the error

```
Not an ARRAY reference
```

---

What would be correct? Well, it's not quite clear what you want.

Maybe you want the keys of the elements of `%cumulative` whose `DIR` attribute equal `BASE`.

```perl
my @matching_keys =                                # 3. Save the results.
   grep { $cumulative{ $_ }->{ DIR } eq "BASE" }   # 2. Filter them.
      keys( %cumulative );                         # 1. Get the keys.
```

(The `->` is optional between indexes, so `$cumulative{ $_ }{ DIR }` is also fine.)

Maybe you don't need the keys. Maybe you want the values of the elements of `%cumulative` whose `DIR` attribute equal `BASE`.

```perl
my @matching_values =                              # 3. Save the results.
   grep { $_->{ DIR } eq "BASE" }                  # 2. Filter them.
      values( %cumulative );                       # 1. Get the values.
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I should have been able to figure that out. sometimes I still psych myself out with data structures and don't look at them from the perspective of what I'm actually looking at. This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: If you want a hash, you can use the keys you now have to build a new (smaller) hash (`my %filtered = map { $_ => $cumulative{ $_ } } @matching_keys;`) . Or you could delete the elements that *don't* match from the existing hash (`delete @cumulative{ grep { $cumulative{ $_ }->{ DIR } ne "BASE" } keys( %cumulative );`).

Comment: I do not need to disturb the cummulative data, I just want to reduce the amount of data I am parsing in the subroutine that only needs BASE data to evaluate. So, I pass the entire data structure to the sub, then I will get the list of `BASE` keys and evaluate from there. Thanks again!